# 2.4.1 Custom Maintenance Mode Page

Tags: magento2, maintenance

given Magento 2.4.1 is different from the others, super confused as to which file to edit in creating a custom Maintenance Mode.

I'll like to show [this Custom Maintenance Mode Page](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/neotericthe-ultimate-under-construction-page/full_screen_preview/67920?_ga=2.257057679.500520974.1608959711-1994684045.1574791208)  instead of default maintenance mode page.  Which file should I edit?  During my search for which file to edit, found:

1. maint-mode.html
2. 503.phtml (which path? one is in vendor directory, another in pub)
3. MaintenanceMode.php

Read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html

Thanks for your attention.  Happy New Year in advance :=)

Comment: please try: https://magecomp.com/blog/custom-maintenance-mode-page-magento-2/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: welcome....... :)